# Start websphere application server

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am new at websphere 8.5 and I have it installed , 
I want to enter the console page localhost:9060/ibm/console

But i am not sure how to start the application server inorder to access the console

Answer (score 11):

Go to the WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\YourProfileName\bin folder and run

```
 startServer.bat/.sh server1
```

If you used defaults during installation/profile creation YourProfileName will be AppSrv1 and server name will be server1.

You can check server name running command:

```
serverStatus.bat/.sh -all
```

To verify if server is started check file:

```
 WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\YourProfileName\logs\server1\SystemOut.log
```

Look for server Open for e-business message.

Answer (score 1):

Follow :

1. please start node agent  go to
   WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\YourProfileName\bin  then use command

   > ./startNode.sh
2. then only you are able to start the server  go to
   WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\YourProfileName\bin   and type

   > ./startServer.sh
   >   "severname"

**Note:** if your `nodeagent` and `dmgr` is up then you are to stop and star your server through console

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what the others said in terms of starting up your server, but you might want to check out your port settings first to verify 9060 is the correct port you're looking for:

```
${PROFILE_HOME}/config/cells/${CELL}/nodes/${NODE}/servers/${SERVER}/server.xml
```

If you installed it locally on a windows machine, C-Drive, 
usually it's C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile (or C:/IBM/WebSphere/Profiles/wp_profile) followed by the path above.

Please don't upvote mine, guys above are providing the main guidance.